# Q: Show that $W$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W =\{(a,b,c) : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \le1\}$

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{v} = (1,0,0)\in W$, but $2\vec{v} = (2,0,0)\notin W$.